# Process Tags in Plugin

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have an Expression Engine plugin that has a file parameter for example:

```
{exp:my_plugin file='/css/css.js'}
```

I can get the parameter in the plugin using

```
$file = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('file');
```

Is there a way to process `$file` to replace any tags, i.e. global variables and snippets, so that I could do something like:

```
{exp:my_plugin file='{global_path}/css.js'}
```

And have `{global_path}` be replaced with the value of global path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your plugin, you can parse the parameter to match global variables:

```
$value = $this->_ee->TMPL->fetch_param('value', '');
$value = $this->_ee->TMPL->parse_globals($value);
```

You can find an example in https://github.com/pvledoux/Pvl_checkif/zipball/master