# {exp:addon:method url=”{site_url}pdf/{segment_1}”} translates url to {site_url}pdf/index in the method

Tags: expressionengine

seems there is some problems with global variables parsing. So

```
{exp:addon:method url="{site_url}pdf/{segment_1}"}
```

pass to method `{site_url}pdf/index`, so `{site_url}` - not parsed and `{segment_1}` - parsed. How to make it parse all global variables?

Thanks

Comment: You can re-parse global vars in your addon too, like [explained here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734738/process-tags-in-plugin/7736940#7736940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with a parse order issue here. First steps to understanding parse order can be found [here](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Parse_Order/) and [here](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf).

There are several ways to address this issue, I would recommend adding a global config variable that contains whatever the site url is. See: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/user_defined.html

Answer (score 1):

You can re-parse global vars in your addon too, like [explained here][1]. [1]: stackoverflow.com/questions/7734738/process-tags-in-plugin/… – pvledoux 1 hour ago